# Is this (crash) a bug in VS2012 c++ compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I was compiling the following code in c++, Visual Studio 2012 (Professional, Update 4)

```
class dum {
    stringstream *ss;
    ~dum() {
        delete ss;
    }
public:
    dum() : ss(NULL) {}
};

int main()
{
    dum a;
    return 0;
}
```

Now I know that the private destructor would force heap allocated objects only, but I would expect a compile error for that. Instead I get a window titled "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing compiler" saying

> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing compiler has stopped working. Windows can check online for a solution to the problem

and then the usual prompts to go online where nothing happens (or gets resolved). Am I doing something wrong or have I stumbled upon a bug in the compiler?

**EDIT**

The code I'm posting is all that's present in a win32 console program (even the main() has this no arguments form) and the only header included is `sstream`.

If you move the destructor to the public section of the class we no longer have a crash, but as I mentioned above this should be a cause for compilation error (namelly *cannot access private member declared in dum*) and not for this pop-up. **The question's targeted to people that can provide an intrinsic or two about what's the problem with the compiler here**, I've seen similar problems before, but that's the smallest code segment that caused such a thing.

Comment: I doubt you could compile this code with `dum : ss(NULL) {}`

Comment: If your compiler crashes when you try to compile that, it's likely a compiler bug. It might not be - you might have done something crazy that you didn't tell us because you didn't realize it was crazy, or some other part of your system configuration might be messed up, or any of a number of other things.

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447799/how-can-i-workaround-this-visual-studio-compiler-bug?rq=1

Comment: A compiler (or any program really) should never, ever crash like that. So yes, it is a bug.

Comment: What happens if fix the syntax bug `dum : ss` to `dum() : ss` ?

Comment: @billz It was a spelling error, I edited the question, the actual code line has always been `dum() : ss(NULL) {}` (haven't noticed the error in posting until Alexey Voytenko pointed this out)

Comment: Still, destructor is private, you are not allowed to construct `a`

Comment: Yes, I mention that in the question (_this should be a cause for compilation error (namelly cannot access private member declared in dum) and not for_...)

Comment: The IntelliSense parser is probably responsible for these kind of compiler bugs not getting discovered sooner, few programmers will ignore the error it produces.  The bug is fixed in VS2013.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to compile the fixed version:

```
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class dum {
    stringstream *ss;
    ~dum() {
        delete ss;
    }
public:
dum() : ss(NULL) {}
};

int main()
{
    dum a;
    return 0;
}
```

gives following compile error for me.
Tried this with VS2012 Ultimate Version 11.061030.00 Update4.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: dum, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  dum.cpp
1>c:\users\randmaniac\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\dum\dum\dum.cpp(19): error C2248: 'dum::~dum' : cannot access private member declared in class 'dum'
1>          c:\users\randmaniac\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\dum\dum\dum.cpp(8) : see declaration of 'dum::~dum'
1>          c:\users\randmaniac\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\dum\dum\dum.cpp(6) : see declaration of 'dum'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

No crash for me on a fairly recent installation of VS2012.

Comment: Bug status: cannot reproduce. No, it is not a bug. Something with configuration. 

@NikosAthanasiou: did you try to rebuild all, restart studio? :) Put this snippet to another project?

Comment: OK that's fair +1, I can confirm it works on Ultimate. I'm getting the bug in Professional with update 4 installed (maybe I should edit that in the question)

Comment: @AlexeyVoytenko That is the snippet being put to a new project, namely a new console project. I have tried it twice. Anyway I'll just write it differently, it's bad enough that I'm at work on a Sunday, I can't waste more time on this. Thnx for  the feedback